# Regex PHP trying to dissect a string

Tags: php, regex

Here is an example of my string:

```
$string = 'Vivamus non risus non diam {some-text-here} varius sollicitudin in non dui. Phasellus egestas {some-more-text-here} quis augue eu pharetra. Curabitur rutrum non lectus et aliquam. Fusce quis rutrum magna. Sed at tristique dui, scelerisque tincidunt tortor. Integer a nibh gravida urna pulvinar vehicula. Curabitur ut felis ut mi imperdiet condimentum {and-some-goes-here-too}. Vestibulum sit amet {of-course-here-as-well} diam mi. Quisque diam dui, convallis dapibus suscipit sit amet, auctor in turpis.';
```

If you notice there are `{these-things-with-text-in-them}` peppered throughout the `$string`. I use this function to pull them out of the `$string`.

```
preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/', $string, $bracket_data);
print '<pre>'; print_r($bracket_data[1]); print '</pre>';
```

Which will spit out this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some-text-here
    [1] => some-more-text-here
    [2] => and-some-goes-here-too
    [3] => of-course-here-as-well
)
```

That does the trick nicely. What I'd like to have is the same result, but with the parts of the `$string` that are *not* within brackets, still using `preg_match_all()`. So in this case using `$string` as an example, the desired result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Vivamus non risus non diam 
    [1] =>  varius sollicitudin in non dui. Phasellus egestas 
    [2] =>  quis augue eu pharetra. Curabitur rutrum non lectus et aliquam. Fusce quis rutrum magna. Sed at tristique dui, scelerisque tincidunt tortor. Integer a nibh gravida urna pulvinar vehicula. Curabitur ut felis ut mi imperdiet condimentum 
    [3] => . Vestibulum sit amet 
    [4] =>  diam mi. Quisque diam dui, convallis dapibus suscipit sit amet, auctor in turpis.
)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or critique for the existing regex I have?

NOTE: The text within the brackets can be found in any arrangement. They can be at the beginning, shoulder-to-shoulder, at the end, and any amount. Same for the text outside of the brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same regex with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split). I've also added `\s*` around the regex to exclude whitespace from the matches.

```
$arr = preg_split('/\s*\{(.*?)\}\s*/', $string);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Vivamus non risus non diam
    [1] => varius sollicitudin in non dui. Phasellus egestas
    [2] => quis augue eu pharetra. Curabitur rutrum non lectus et aliquam. Fusce quis rutrum magna. Sed at tristique dui, scelerisque tincidunt tortor. Integer a nibh gravida urna pulvinar vehicula. Curabitur ut felis ut mi imperdiet condimentum
    [3] => . Vestibulum sit amet
    [4] => diam mi. Quisque diam dui, convallis dapibus suscipit sit amet, auctor in turpis.
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/149105)

Answer (score 2):

The preg_split (as Amal suggested) would work, but if you want everything in one array, the following regex will be helpful. It will include the text before, within and after the `{..}`:

```
/(.*?)\{(.*?)\}([^{]*)/
```

http://regex101.com/r/wS4iJ1

Comment: And what about the order? This is not quite what the OP wanted. See here: https://eval.in/149147